# Using email address as route parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use an email address as a route parameter. When I first click the link, the page loads fine, but when I try access the url directly I get the following error:

`Cannot GET /users/edit/susannaallison%40emergent.com/`

This is an example of what I'm trying to use:

`http://localhost:5555/users/edit/susannaallison%40emergent.com/`

I know it has to do with the `.` in the email, but I'm trying to find a way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the way I got around this was slightly "hacky".

I replaced the `.` with a unique string that I made up, then inside my controller I replaced that unique string with a `.`.

It's really hacky, but it was the only way around this that I could find.

UPDATE:

I tried this again recently and it just seemed to work with the email address in the URL, above solution isn't needed anymore I guess...